# Obtaining table names for sqlite SQL join in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a need to join standard android's tables (like contacts and call log) using SQL. It is possible using the rawQuery or query methods of SQLiteDatabase class. But for the methods to work properly I need to know table names that I can provide in a raw SQL query.

Example. I want to execute query like this:

SELECT * FROM Contacts as c INNER JOIN Call_Log as l ON c.number=l.number

I know how to get field names (like CallLog.Calls.NUMBER), but I don't know how to get the name of a standard table that every android has. It is possible to hardcode the name, but the way with something like CallLog.TABLE_NAME looks much more reliable. So, where can I find an analogue of CallLog.TABLE_NAME?

Answer (score -1):

Your asking for a lot of info, but this is a good summation of how to access the contacts table and how to create your own SQL table and update it with information you get from other tables.

To do any type of search of the Contacts Provider, your app must have READ_CONTACTS permission. To request this, add this  element to your manifest file as a child element of :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

To do any type of search of the Call Log, your app must have READ_CALL_LOG permission. To request this, add this  element to your manifest file as a child element of :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Code below on how to access Phone Call History

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
Cursor c = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, null);

String num= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));// for  number
String name= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));// for name
String duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// for duration
int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// for call type, Incoming or out going.
```

This technique tries to match a search string to the name of a contact or contacts in the Contact Provider's ContactsContract.Contacts table. You usually want to display the results in a ListView, to allow the user to choose among the matched contacts.

Saving data to a database is ideal for repeating or structured data, such as contact information. This class assumes that you are familiar with SQL databases in general and helps you get started with SQLite databases on Android. The APIs you'll need to use a database on Android are available in the android.database.sqlite package.

One of the main principles of SQL databases is the schema: a formal declaration of how the database is organized. The schema is reflected in the SQL statements that you use to create your database. You may find it helpful to create a companion class, known as a contract class, which explicitly specifies the layout of your schema in a systematic and self-documenting way.

A contract class is a container for constants that define names for URIs, tables, and columns. The contract class allows you to use the same constants across all the other classes in the same package. This lets you change a column name in one place and have it propagate throughout your code.

A good way to organize a contract class is to put definitions that are global to your whole database in the root level of the class. Then create an inner class for each table that enumerates its columns.

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
  // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
  // make the constructor private.
  private FeedReaderContract() {}

  /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
  public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
      public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
    }
}
```

Once you have defined how your database looks, you should implement methods that create and maintain the database and tables. Here are some typical statements that create and delete a table:

```
 private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
 private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
 private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
   "CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
    FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + TEXT_TYPE + " )";

  private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
  "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;
```

Just like files that you save on the device's internal storage, Android stores your database in private disk space that's associated application. Your data is secure, because by default this area is not accessible to other applications.

A useful set of APIs is available in the SQLiteOpenHelper class. When you use this class to obtain references to your database, the system performs the potentially long-running operations of creating and updating the database only when needed and not during app startup. All you need to do is call getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase().

To use SQLiteOpenHelper, create a subclass that overrides the onCreate(), onUpgrade() and onOpen() callback methods. You may also want to implement onDowngrade(), but it's not required.

For example, here's an implementation of SQLiteOpenHelper that uses some of the commands shown above:

```
  public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
```

// If you change the database schema, you must increment the database           version.
      public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
      public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

```
  public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
 }
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
    // to simply to discard the data and start over
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
 }
 public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)     {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

}

To access your database, instantiate your subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper:

FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext());
Put Information into a Database

Insert data into the database by passing a ContentValues object to the insert() method:

```
// Gets the data repository in write mode
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

// Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE, subtitle);

// Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
long newRowId = db.insert(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
The first argument for insert() is simply the table name.
```

The second argument tells the framework what to do in the event that the ContentValues is empty (i.e., you did not put any values). If you specify the name of a column, the framework inserts a row and sets the value of that column to null. If you specify null, like in this code sample, the framework does not insert a row when there are no values.

To read from a database, use the query() method, passing it your selection criteria and desired columns. The method combines elements of insert() and update(), except the column list defines the data you want to fetch, rather than the data to insert. The results of the query are returned to you in a Cursor object.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

// Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
// you will actually use after this query.
String[] projection = {
   FeedEntry._ID,
   FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE,
   FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE
};

// Filter results WHERE "title" = 'My Title'
String selection = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { "My Title" };

// How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
String sortOrder =
FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + " DESC";

Cursor c = db.query(
   FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,                     // The table to query
   projection,                               // The columns to return
   selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE      clause
   selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
   null,                                     // don't group the rows
   null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
   sortOrder                                 // The sort order
 );
```

To look at a row in the cursor, use one of the Cursor move methods, which you must always call before you begin reading values. Generally, you should start by calling moveToFirst(), which places the "read position" on the first entry in the results. For each row, you can read a column's value by calling one of the Cursor get methods, such as getString() or getLong(). For each of the get methods, you must pass the index position of the column you desire, which you can get by calling getColumnIndex() or getColumnIndexOrThrow(). For example:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
  long itemId = cursor.getLong(
  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FeedEntry._ID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the long answer, but my question was about the table name of a standard provider like android.provider.CallLog. How can I get the name for it to be used in the SQL? I know there is CONTENT_URI static field in every provider in standard android's API, but there's no field like TABLE_NAME. Is there a reliable algorithm to extract the table name from CONTENT_URI? Or there's nothing reliable in Android and it is the only option I have - just to hardcode the table names? Did Android developers thought that nobody should use plain old SQL with the standard tables like contacts and calls?